# Unable to delete route53 record set via boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I have following boto3 script:

```
Import boto3

ChangeBatch={
    'Changes': [
        {
            'Action': 'DELETE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': 'test.example.com.',
                'Region': 'us-west-1',
                'SetIdentifier': 'test1',
                'AliasTarget': {
                    'HostedZoneId': '**675',
                    'DNSName': 'testexample.example.com.',
                    'EvaluateTargetHealth': 'True'
                },
                'HealthCheckId': '**-**-**-675'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the above code it does not delete anything. This is a latency based routing policy. Not sure what am I doing wrong I checked online and looked at aws documentation this is the suggested way to delete recordset.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was missing type.

```
Import boto3

ChangeBatch={
    'Changes': [
        {
            'Action': 'DELETE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': 'test.example.com.',
                'Region': 'us-west-1',
                'Type': 'A'
                'SetIdentifier': 'test1',
                'AliasTarget': {
                    'HostedZoneId': '**675',
                    'DNSName': 'testexample.example.com.',
                    'EvaluateTargetHealth': 'True'
                },
                'HealthCheckId': '**-**-**-675'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```